# Solve cubic polynomial

Tags: polynomials, cubics

How can I solve this third-degree polynomial?
I want to solve it for $y$.

$x=y^3+y-9$

I can simplify it to $x+9=y(y^2+1)$ but I don't get any further.

Comment: Are you trying to invert $f(y)=y^3+y-9$?

Comment: Need cubic equation. [like quadratic but more involved]. Maybe try "Cardano's formula",

Comment: You made a mistake. It is $x+9=y(y^2+1)$. Why do you write $x$? Is it another variable?

Answer (score 4):

That's a job for [Cardano's formula](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Cardano_formula). First, however, we have to ensure the function is invertible: if $f(y)=y^3+y-9$, then $f'(y)=3y^2+1$ and, as this is everywhere positive, we're done.

Next rewrite to $y^3+y-9-x=0$, to get
$$
y=\sqrt[3]{\frac{x+9}{2}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{27}+\frac{(x+9)^2}{4}}}+
\sqrt[3]{\frac{x+9}{2}-\sqrt{\frac{1}{27}+\frac{(x+9)^2}{4}}}
$$

Comment: And there is only one solution as the derivative is $3y^2+1$ ie positive....

Comment: @dmtri Yes: the discriminant (what's under the square root) is positive, so there's no choice in order to obtain the unique real root.